# HTML/CSS: Positioning a background element responsively

Tags: html, css

[Here's a rough mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIPc5.png) of what I am trying to create, I have the page laid out but the only piece left that I am struggling with is positioning the background circle in a way that is responsive.

I tried using position absolute with top & left positioning but even small screen changes will completely throw off the layout.

What would you guys recommend as the best way to approach this? Thanks!

code demo: https://jsfiddle.net/e91g8tdj/11/

[image: Here's a rough mockup]

Comment: That's a rather complex design to be trying to achieve with CSS... can you not just use an image that combines all the elements?

Comment: Hi, could you post a demo of your code? It'd be hard to provide suggestions without it.

Comment: Things that come to me: `background-size: cover` or `contain` as well as a using a mix of `top: XX%` and `transform: translate(-XX%, -XX%`).

Comment: Sorry about the lack of code guys! I put together a small demo here. https://jsfiddle.net/e91g8tdj/11/

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your Css :

```
.yourClassHere{
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't provided any demo of your working code so had to create a responsive one from scratch using css only. It might look a bit janky in the snippet below so its better to copy the code in a file and view in a browser.
Let me know in the comments if it breaks.

```css
*,
      *::before,
      *::after {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
      }
      .container {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
      }
      .divider1,
      .divider2 {
        width: 100%;
        height: 50vh;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
      }
      .divider1 {
        background-color: silver;
        gap: 2rem;
      }
      .divider2 {
        background-color: gray;
      }
      .row1,
      .row2,
      .row3 {
        width: 90%;
        height: 25%;
        background-color: #2a2a2a;
      }
      .row3 {
          width: 40%;
          height: 70%;
      }
      .row1-row2-wrapper, .row3-wrapper {
        width: 40%;
    height: inherit !important;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: end;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
      }
      .row1-row2-wrapper {
          flex-direction: column;
          justify-content: center;
    gap: 2rem;
    z-index: 1;
      }
      .row1-row2-wrapper::before, .row1-row2-wrapper::after, .row3::before, .row3::after {
          content: '';
          position: absolute;
          border: 4px solid #fff;
          border-radius: 50%;
      }
      .row1-row2-wrapper::before {
        inset: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    height: 105%;
    width: 100%;
      }
      .row1-row2-wrapper::after {
        width: 2rem;
    height: 2rem;
    bottom: -18%;
    right: 24%;
      }
      .row3::before {
        width: 1.4rem;
    height: 1.4rem;
    top: 18%;
    right: 20%;
      }
      .row3::after {
          width: 1rem;
          height: 1rem;
    top: 25%;
    right: 16%;
      }
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <div class="divider1">
          <div class="row1-row2-wrapper">
              <div class="row1"></div>
              <div class="row2"></div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="divider2">
          <div class="row3-wrapper">
              <div class="row3"></div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```